# Nodes repetidos xml c#

Tags: c#, xml

Olá, precisava de uma ajuda. Tenho este código:

```
XmlNodeList xnList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Line");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
    string salescode = xn["ProductCode"].InnerText;
    if (salescode == code)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(salescode);
    }
    else;
}
```

E esse código apresenta o seguinte:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando há numeros repetidos, só quero que apareça o primeiro. Como posso fazer isso ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode armazenar os valores já exibidos em uma lista, e não exibir o que já consta na lista.

Por exemplo:

```
List<string> valoresExibidos = new List<string>();

XmlNodeList xnList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Line");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
    string salescode = xn["ProductCode"].InnerText;
    if (salescode == code)
    {
        if (valoresExibidos.Contains(salescode))
        {
            continue; // isso faz o laço pular para o próximo nó
        }
        else
        {
            valoresExibidos.Add(salesCode);
            Console.WriteLine(salescode);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADO RENAN ! Era exatamente o que precisava ! Abraço

Comment: @DC Percebi que você fez várias perguntas e nenhuma tem resposta aceita, então acho pertinente te avisar que você sempre pode escolher **uma resposta** como correta para a sua pergunta. É uma forma de mostrar que o seu problema foi resolvido com a resposta. Para fazer isto, basta clicar no **✓** do lado esquerdo da publicação.